# Intern - define different commands / arguments to run different tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

I have a project with 2 functional Suites, the structure is like this:

```
- /tests
--- /sign
------ sign.js
--- /buy
------ buy.js
--- intern.js
- /node_modules
- ....
```

On my `intern.js` I have this

```
//...
functionalSuites: [ 'tests/sign/sign', 'tests/buy/buy'],  
//...
```

And to run the test `intern-runner config=tests/intern`

So far so good, 2/2 tests passed.

I would like to know if it's possible to pass some arguments to execute only a part of the `functionalSuites`

ex:

```
intern-runner config=tests/intern --sign
```

And somehow it would run only the functionalSuite `tests/sign/sign`

And if I pass `intern-runner config=tests/intern --all` it would run all functionalSuite tests.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `grep` parameter introduced in [Intern 2.1 release announce](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/09/12/intern-2-1-released/). With `grep` you can target one specific test or a class of tests depending on your naming convention.

In our case, the `functionSuites` settings contains only `'test/functional/**/*` to be sure that no functional test is forgotten by the CI process. And we use the `grep` attribute during the script development.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

**The simple solution** is:
`intern-runner config=tests/intern functionalSuites=test/sign/sign`

The more complicated (but good for long term) is to write a filter function by yourself (hmm, maybe you can make a request to https://github.com/theintern/intern?). We do have our custom filter, but it's too complicated to write down here. If you make a request to Intern, maybe I will try to spend sometime to make a pullrequest for it (or maybe someone else) Anyway the result I get is:

(I have 2 files named file1_func.js, file2_func.js and some more files)
[image]

Comment: I didn't know about that parameters. Thanks. I'll take a look

Comment: -f is my custom filter, you will not find it in Intern. But I guess you can try with `functionalSuites`